# Remove a User from GCP project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

How do I remove a user from a GCP project. 
I have a requirement to delete a particular user and service account for a particular GCP project.

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
   filename=os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'],
   scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])
```

I tried using this

```
def modify_policy_remove_member(policy, role, member):
    """Removes a  member from a role binding."""
    binding = next(b for b in policy["bindings"] if b["role"] == role)
    if "members" in binding and member in binding["members"]:
        binding["members"].remove(member)
    print(binding)
    return policy
```

Another way I tried was

```
service.projects().serviceAccounts().disable(
        name='projects/-/serviceAccounts/' + email).execute()
```

I am getting the following message.

> Permission iam.serviceAccounts.disable is required to perform this
>   operation on

Comment: To delete or disable a service account, you need either `roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin` or `roles/editor`. To remove a user, see this link: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#deleting. To Disable a user see this: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#disabling. I provided this as an answer to help others facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

To add or update existing user's IAM policy, you should at least have 'resourcemanager.projects.setIamPolicy' permission. Or you should be the owner of the project.
To make sure you have adequate permission check your IAM role in console then run:

'gcloud iam roles describe roles/'

This would list all the permissions you have associated with your current role.

Answer (score 1):

To allow a user to manage **Service Accounts**, grant one of the following roles:

- **Service Account User** (`roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`): Grants permissions to get, list, or impersonate a service account.
- **Service Account Admin** (`roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin`): Includes Service Account User permissions and also grants permissions to create, update, delete, and set or get the Cloud IAM policy on a service account.

As per the question, please note that there is a difference between `disable` and `delete` of Service Accounts. But, required permissions are the same.

To `disable` a service account, at minimum the user must be granted the **Service Account Admin** role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin`) or the **Editor** primitive role (`roles/editor`). See [this link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#disabling).

To `delete` a service account, at minimum the user must be granted the **Service Account Admin** role (`roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin`) or the **Editor** primitive role (`roles/editor`). See [this link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#deleting).

If you want Code Examples and Required Role details, refer to [Official GCloud Creating and managing service accounts Docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).